# how to load a sectioned CSV file to an excel sheet?

Tags: vba, csv, excel, excel-2010

### CSV file:

```
#3GMACRO,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
IMSI,IMEI,Date,Time,UMTS MACRO-UARFCNDL,UMTS MACRO-PrimaryScramblingCode,UMTS MACRO-CPICHTxPower,UMTS MACRO-PLMNCellId,UMTS MACRO- RNCId,UMTS MACRO-MCC,UMTS MACRO-MNC,UMTS MACRO - LAC,UMTS MACRO - RAC,UMTS MACRO - MaxUETxPower,UMTS MACRO - MeasuredRSCP
2.6275E+14,3.57539E+14,20100107,160000,10662,11,-99,268435456,0,0,0,1,0,0,-74

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
#3GFEMTO,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
IMSI,IMEI,Date,Time,UMTS FEMTOS-UARFCNDL,UMTS FEMTOS-PrimaryScramblingCode,UMTS FEMTOS-CPICHTxPower,UMTS FEMTOS-PLMNCellId,UMTS FEMTOS-RNCId,UMTS FEMTOS-MCC,UMTS FEMTOS-MNC,UMTS FEMTOS-LAC,UMTS FEMTOS-RAC,UMTS FEMTOS-MaxUETxPower,UMTS FEMTOS- MeasuredRSCP
2.6275E+14,3.57539E+14,20100107,160000,10687,252,-24,61,0,610,3956,486,11,5,-102

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
#2GMACRO,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
IMSI,IMEI,Date,Time,GSM MACRO_CellID,GSM MACRO-MCC,GSM MACRO-MNC,GSM MACRO-LAC,GSM MACRO-RAC,GSM MACRO-Max permitted UE Tx power (SIB3),GSM MACRO-Measure RSSI,,,,
2.6275E+14,3.57539E+14,20100107,160000,GSM_Cell_Id=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,,,,
```

i want this csv file to be loaded into an excel sheet as an individual section when I click load only once (ie each section should go to separate worksheet in excel)

CSV file contain Section name , header and data

Below are the section names in CSv file

## 3GMACRO

## 3GFEMTO

## 2GMACRO

Below are the Header names in CSv file
IMSI,IMEI,Date,Time,GSM MACRO_CellID,GSM MACRO-MCC,GSM MACRO-MNC............ etc

3 worksheets should have headers and data after loading CSV file.

Please help me in doing so.

Thanks in advance
[image]

hi
this is what the code i tried but its not working perfectly as needed.

```
Sub loadData()

'Runtime error handling
'On Error Resume Next

'Unprotect the password protected sheet for loading csv data
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=pass
 
'Variable declaration
 Dim strFilePath As String, strFilename As String, strFullPath As String
    Dim lngCounter As Long
    Dim oConn As Object, oRS As Object, oFSObj As Object

    'Get a text file name
    strFullPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Please select text file...")
 'MsgBox "stringfullpath" & strFullPath
 
 
    If strFullPath = "False" Then Exit Sub  'User pressed Cancel on the open file dialog
    

    'This gives us a full path name e.g. C:tempfolderfile.txt
    'We need to split this into path and file name
    Set oFSObj = CreateObject("SCRIPTING.FILESYSTEMOBJECT")

    strFilePath = oFSObj.GetFile(strFullPath).ParentFolder.Path
    strFilename = oFSObj.GetFile(strFullPath).Name


    'Open an ADO connection to the folder specified
    Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.CONNECTION")
    oConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
               "Data Source=" & strFilePath & ";" & _
               "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"""

    Set oRS = CreateObject("ADODB.RECORDSET")

    'Now actually open the text file and import into Excel
    'oRS.Open "SELECT * FROM " & strFilename & " , oConn"
    
    oRS.Open "SELECT * FROM " & strFilename, oConn
    While Not oRS.EOF
        Sheets("Neighbour3GMacro").Range("A3").CopyFromRecordset oRS
        'Sheets.Add Type:=Application.GetOpenFilename & "     *.csv"
        Sheets("Neighbour3GFemto").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset oRS
        Sheets("Neighbour2GMacro").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset oRS
        
    Wend

    oRS.Close
    oConn.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please provide your code as you have it already and point out where you are having trouble? People don't mind helping, but they'll rarely want to do all your work for you.

Comment: It seems easier to call any text processing program (perl,awk,etc) first to segment the input in three files and then load them programatically one by one with a simple "open".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Split` function to get an array and use this array to fill a Row. Here is a simple solution.

*You will need to change `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, `Sheet3` to your worksheet-names and might want to add functionality to ignore header lines. If you have a fix ColumnCount you can also replace the `Ubound` function with an integer variable.*

```
Sub loadData2()
Dim strFullPath As String
Dim oFSOBj As Object 'Scripting.FileSystemObject'
Dim oFileStream As Object 'Scripting.TextStream'

Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim iRow As Long
Dim startRow As Long
Dim startColumn As Integer

Dim line As String

    'Please insert Error Handling etc.'

    'Get a text file name '
    strFullPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Please select text file...")
    If strFullPath = "False" Then Exit Sub  'User pressed Cancel on the open file dialog'

    Set oFSOBj = CreateObject("SCRIPTING.FILESYSTEMOBJECT")
    Set oFileStream = oFSOBj.GetFile(strFullPath).OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

    Set targetSheet = Sheet1
    iRow = 0
    startRow = 3
    startColumn = 1

    While (Not oFileStream.AtEndOfStream)
        line = oFileStream.ReadLine
        If (Left(line, 1) = "#") Then
            iRow = 0
            If (Left(line, 8) = "#3GMACRO") Then Set targetSheet = Sheet1
            If (Left(line, 8) = "#3GFEMTO") Then Set targetSheet = Sheet2
            If (Left(line, 8) = "#2GMACRO") Then Set targetSheet = Sheet3
        ElseIf Trim(line) <> vbNullString Then  'Else Block: line has content'
            csline = Split(line, ",")
            targetSheet.Range(targetSheet.Cells(startRow + iRow, startColumn), targetSheet.Cells(startRow + iRow, startColumn + UBound(csline))).Value2 = csline
            iRow = iRow + 1
        End If
    Wend
    oFileStream.Close
    Set oFileStream = Nothing
    Set oFSOBj = Nothing
End Sub
```